# vcvarsall.bat unusable in PowerShell

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, msvc12

I want to use x64 Native Tools Command Prompt in PowerShell. I run "vcvarsall.bat amd64" in it but it didn't enter the Developer Command env.[situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMAUS.png)

Comment: What happens when you run it in the developer command prompt?

Comment: I run the bat in PowerShell but it quickly quit and return to the PowerShell after it output "[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x64' ", but if directly run the x64 Native Tools Command Prompt in Start menu it works。i put a Screenshots in the link of sitution word.